# Show $D = \{f \in C^{2}[0,1]): f(x) > 0, \ \forall x \in [0,1], \|f'\|_{\infty}<1, |f''(0)| > 2\}$ is open w.r.t Sup Norm. Full Proof Verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Show $D = \{f \in C^{2}[0,1]): f(x) > 0, \ \forall x \in [0,1], \|f'\|_{\infty}<1, |f''(0)| > 2\}$ is open w.r.t Sup Norm.

Sup Norm = $\|f\|_{2,\infty, [0,1]} = sup_{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)| + sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)| + sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f''(x)|$

I had originally posted this question trying to seek clarification on a particular part, but as I've gone over that solution it didn't make sense to me so I've instead just attempted to reproduce a full solution and get feedback on this from start to finish.

**Attempt:**

To start I have to examine what is precisely meant by the three conditions given.

*Condition 1:* $f(x) > 0 \forall \ x \in [0,1]$:

By the Extreme value theorem, there exists a value $x_{1} \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(x_{1}) = minimum$ over $[0,1]$. By condition $f(x) > 0$, this means there exists a $\delta_{1} > 0 $ s.t $f(x) > f(x_{1}) > \delta_{1} > 0$. In particular this means $f(x_{1}) - \delta_{1} > 0$.

*Condition 2:* $\|f'(x)\|_{\infty} < 1$:

By the EVT again, there exists an $x_{2} \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f'(x_{2}) = maximum$ over $[0,1]$. By condition $\|f'(x)\|_{\infty} < 1$, there exists a $\delta_{2} >0$ s.t. $\|f'(x)\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f'(x)| = f'(x_{2}) < 1 - \delta_{2} < 1$.

*Condition 3:* $|f''(0)| > 2$:

This condition means there exists a $\delta_{3} > 0 $ s.t. $f''(0) > \delta_{3} > 2$. Equivalently one can say: $f''(0) - \delta_{3} > 2$. Also $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}f''(x) - \delta_{3} > f''(0) - \delta_{3} > 2$. (Not sure if this last observations means much.)

Therefore in order to show that $D$ is open (i.e $B_{\delta}(f) \subset D$), I have to establish that $g(x) \in B_{\delta}(f)$. This means $g(x)$ has to satisfy the three observations above.

**Proof:**

Let $y \in [0,1]$, let $\frac{\delta_{g}}{3} = \frac{min(\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}, \delta_{3})}{3}$

1) Consider $\|g(y) - f(y)\|_{\infty} < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \sup_{y \in [0,1]}|g(y) - f(y)| < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow -\frac{\delta_{g}}{3} < g(y) - f(y) < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow g(y) \geq f(y) - \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} > f(x_{1}) - \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \geq f(x_{1}) - \frac{\delta_{1}}{3} > 0 \\ \therefore g(y) > 0$

2) Consider $\|g'(y) - f'(y) \|_{\infty} < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \sup_{y \in [0,1]}|g'(y) - f'(y)| < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow -\frac{\delta_{g}}{3} < g'(y) - f'(y) < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow g'(y) \leq f'(y) + \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} < f'(x_{2}) + \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} < 1 - \delta_{2} + \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \leq 1 - \delta_{2} + \frac{\delta_{2}}{3} < 1 - \frac{\delta_{2}}{3} < 1  \\ \therefore g'(y) < 1$

3) Consider $\|g''(0) - f''(0)\|_{\infty} < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} $

$\Rightarrow \sup_{y \in [0,1]} |g''(0) - f''(0)\| < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow -\frac{\delta_{g}}{3} < g''(0) - f''(0) < \frac{\delta_{g}}{3} \\ \Rightarrow g''(0) > f''(0) - \frac{\delta_{g}}{3}$ [**Really stuck here**]

Comments:

My first concern is whether the first two parts were interpreted in the correct way or am I missing things from my reasoning. As for the third condition, I am utterly loss......Help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: The term "sup norm" is usually reserved for the function only, not its derivatives.

Comment: Does the norm that I provided have a name or just it's the norm for this problem? Also is there anyway I could delete the prior post I had done to this that was similar? This one is more detailed.

Comment: It does not have a special name. You should know better than me if it is just the norm for this problem.

Comment: Well if that is the case practice worksheet I am doing this from called it the sup norm

Comment: It is better to show that the complement of $D$ is closed.

Comment: @xpaul what made you come to that conclusion? I ask because fortunately this time I was told that this set is open, but  in scenarios where I might not know I'm going to have to deduce what the status of the set is. ID the onyl way to do such to to actually work it all out and see what happens? or are there possible key notions I could try before doing the heavy lifting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "This condition means there exists a $\delta_{3} > 0 $ s.t. $f''(0) > \delta_{3} > 2$." You're missing the negative case, e.g., $f''(0)=-3$

I would let $\delta_3 = |f''(0)| - 2.$ Then $|g''(0)-f''(0)|<\delta_3$ implies $ ||g''(0)|-|f''(0)||<\delta_3.$  Thus $|g''(0)| > |f''(0)| - \delta_3 =2.$

Comment: When I was thinking of the problem yesterday I was asking myself should I concern myself with the negative case as well. The way that the condition is specified, I suppose I should also examine the neagative case. I see why your $\delta_{3}$ makes sense, but what line of thinking did you take to make this conclusion? I'm just curious so I can perhaps try and implement that sort of thinking for future situations.

Comment: Good question. I pictured $2 < |f''(0)|$ on the number line. Thus we have $|f''(0)|-2$ worth of distance to the left of $|f''(0)|$ for $|g''(0)|$ to also be $>2.$ I.e., if $|g''(0)|$ was within $|f''(0)|-2$ of $|f''(0)|,$ then $|g''(0)|>2.$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, notice that $\phi, \psi : C^2[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(f) 
= \|f'\|_\infty$ and $\psi(f) = |f''(0)|$ are continuous functions w.r.t the given norm on $C^2[0,1]$.

You already more-less established that $\{f \in C^2[0,1] : f(x) > 0, \forall x\in [0,1]\}$ is open so we have
\begin{align}
D &= \{f \in C^2[0,1] : f(x) > 0, \forall x\in [0,1]\} \cap \{f \in C^2[0,1] : \|f'\|_\infty < 1\} \cap \{f \in C^2[0,1] : |f''(0)| > 2\}\\
&= \{f \in C^2[0,1] : f(x) > 0, \forall x\in [0,1]\}  \cap \phi^{-1}\big((-\infty, 1)\big) \cap \psi^{-1}\big((2, \infty)\big)
\end{align}
which is open as an intersection of three open sets.